# Start mysql in MAMP PRO with an error

Tags: php, mysql, mamp-pro

I have several problems when using mysql on MAMP PRO on my Mac.

It won't start.

Here's my error log file:

```
180505 14:15:26 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
180505 14:15:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2018-05-05 14:15:27 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-05 14:15:27 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-05 14:15:27 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 9662 ...
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 685032976
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2018-05-05 14:15:27 9662 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace casaecli_wp305/wpi1_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules uses space ID: 1971 at filepath: ./casaecli_wp305/wpi1_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules.ibd. Cannot open tablespace masteroftime/wp_aiowps_events which uses space ID: 1971 at filepath: ./masteroftime/wp_aiowps_events.ibd
2018-05-05 14:15:27 7fff96e89380  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./masteroftime/wp_aiowps_events.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
180505 14:15:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

How can I resolve it?

Or can I export a database .sql without opening Phpmyadmin?

Comment: To answer your last question, this doesn't really have to do with phpMyAdmin at all because your MySQL server won't start. phpMyAdmin is an interface to connect to a MySQL database instance, and since MySQL won't start, no client program (such as phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or the command-line tools) will be able to connect. You'll have to find a way to get the MySQL server started first.

Comment: Is this a new install? Existing database installation that's suddenly broken? Did you copy the database files from a different MySQL server? Restore files from backup? Did you have any trouble with the hard drive or corrupt files? As you can see, the error message is talking about missing files on the disk, so it would be a good idea to figure out why several of your database files are suddenly missing.

Comment: My computer kernel panicked and it corrupted some of my MAMP databases. I had to revert to backups of my /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56 folder (your DB location may be different). There's some helpful tricks to try first here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898787/mamp-pro-crashes-mysql-will-not-start-on-reboot